# Bring matrix to reduced echelon form when it contains symbolic variables

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

i have a Linear algebra course, and if there is one thing that throws me off it is when the teachers drop a unknown variable into the mix.
let's say we have the matrix(i just made up the numbers):
$$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 3 & 2 \\
    0 & x+3 & 3 \\
    0 & 2 & 3 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$
Then i want to make $(x+3)$ into a $1$, but the only way i would usually do this is $\frac{1}{(x+3)}$ but then i have to setup a rule that says $ x \neq -3$ because i cannot divide by 0. But in a assignment it would say something different like $ x\neq \sqrt{\text{something else}}$. Now is it okay that i just "make it work" by noting that $x \neq -3$ in a specific step? or is it possible to get the $1$ in a different way? my basic algebra is very bad which is tilting me a lot. What would you guys say? 
i of course understand that it might be a question i should ask someone with authority - but i wanted to present the question in a general way because i stumble on this all the time.

Comment: I would just divide by $x+3$ as you suggest, and then just mention that the result you get assumes $x \neq -3$. Then treat the case $x=-3$ separately. If $x = -3$, then that entry in the matrix is zero, and you can just put it in echelon form as normal (without any symbolic variable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming constant $x$, multiplying the second row by $\frac{1}{x+3}$ is certainly valid. You are right in thinking that we must keep track of the fact that we assumed $x \neq -3$. Each time we consider two cases like this, we just are just creating a fork in the ‘tree’ of echelon forms, and so in this case we just have two possible forms.

$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 3 \\
0 & 2 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
$ if $x = -3$

and

$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & \frac{3}{x+3} \\
0 & 2 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
$ otherwise.

Both of these matrices can then be brought to reduced row echelon form.

Answer (score 2):

At some point in the process, you’ll have to divide by a term involving $x$ that might equal zero, but you can delay that and keep the calculations simpler in the meantime by swapping rows to move it to the bottom, eventually arriving at: $$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-\frac52\\0&1&\frac32\\0&0&-\frac32(x+1)\end{bmatrix}.$$ At this point, you can’t avoid the potential zero division any longer. The matrix has two possible RREFs, but the good news is that if $x=-1$, the matrix is already in RREF, so there’s nothing more to do for that case.

If you don’t do this row swap, you eventually get to $$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&{2x-3\over x+3}\\0&1&{3\over x+3}\\0&0&3{x+1\over x+3}\end{bmatrix},$$ with the entire third column undefined if $x=-3$. If $x=-1$, you can’t reduce the matrix any further, so you now have two special cases to deal with: $x=-1$ and $x=-3$. From the previous paragraph, we know that there’s really nothing special about the latter, but going this route you’ll have to check it separately anyway, just in case.

You won’t always be able to defer potential divisions by zero until the end like this, in which case you’ll just have to suck it up, note the exceptional cases and deal with them.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your matrix is given by 
$$  A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 & 2 \\ 0 & x+3 & 3 \\ 0& 2 & 3 \end{bmatrix}  $$

If you follow like above you still need to get the $3$ rd row to have a $0$

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & \frac{3}{x+3} \\ 0& 2 & 3 \end{bmatrix}   $$

Multiply $R_{2}$ by $2$ and subtract

$$ R_{3} - 2 \cdot R_{2} =  \begin{bmatrix} 0 &  2 & \frac{6}{x+3} \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 2 & 3\end{bmatrix} =   \begin{bmatrix} 0 &  0 & \frac{3(x+1)}{x+3} \end{bmatrix} $$
$$ A= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & \frac{3}{x+3} \\ 0& 0 & \frac{3(x+1)}{x+3} \end{bmatrix} $$

Then multiply again